# Activating enterprise adds "breaking changes" on filter. How to avoid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Normally in Development activating features should be "on demand" to avoid having to change undesired breaking changes.

This is different in ag-grid. When ONLY activating the license it adds features - which we don't want. We want to activate them explicitly. Now we basically have to change a lot of things.

### The actual question at this moment

Without enterprise you have the simple filters, they look like this (we just changed a few styles)

[image: Simple Filters Ag Grid]

Now when activating ONLY the license it suddenly changes to this (a top menu with 3 options of which the middle one is the filter which looks obviously odd because we didn't style it yet as we neither want nor need it):

[image: Enterprise Filters]

Now not only a new menu appeared but also the SimpleFilter changed to unwanted `Set` filter. I overcame the `Set` Filter by explicitly recreating the SimpleFilter like this

```
{
filterOptions: [
    SimpleFilter.CONTAINS,
    SimpleFilter.NOT_CONTAINS,
    SimpleFilter.EQUALS,
    SimpleFilter.NOT_EQUAL,
    SimpleFilter.STARTS_WITH,
    SimpleFilter.ENDS_WITH,
    SimpleFilter.BLANK,
    SimpleFilter.NOT_BLANK,
  ],
  defaultOption: SimpleFilter.CONTAINS,
}
```

We were confused that there isn't a ready-to-use flag/preset...

**But furthermore we don't want that 3 option bar. We just want the old version of this menu! How can this be done?**

Answer (score 2):

In the column menu you can select which tabs to show using the column definition menuTabs property.

If you only want to show the filter tab in the column menu for the COUNTRY column, use this column definition code:
`{ field: 'country', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab'], }`